# What happens when you save an exe file in a text editor?

Tags: text, save, editor, exe, executable

A long time ago I remember opening an executable file (.exe) in a text editor, and saving it back to the hard drive. The executable, needless to say, didn't open.

My understanding is that a file is a series of bytes. In the case of a text file, these bytes encode letters. In the case of an executable file, these bytes encode instructions.

Both text files and executable files are simply a series of bytes, and my understanding is that those bytes are only given meaning by how you interpret them. The character 'a' could be a letter in the word apple, or one byte in a legitimate program coding for some low level operation. Likewise, all the instructions of the program can be interpreted as gibberish characters in the context of being a text document.

So my question then is why, since I haven't changed anything in the file before saving it, it would no longer work as a program. Shouldn't the series of bytes be the exact same?

What specifically changes about this file when I use a text editor which causes it to no longer execute even though the filename and contents are the same?

Comment: I answered the question generally.  For a more specific answer, include the text-editor and operating system you used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be due to many factors, including the following:

- Not all characters are printable.  Non-printable characters might not save back correctly.
- Some text editors ensure the file ends with a newline by default (ie: vi).
- Accidentally changing even one character could make the program no longer a valid executable.
- Some text editors change newline characters to the OS default.
- Autocorrect might inadvertently change characters.
- If the file was saved in a different encoding, the characters might save differently.

To investigate further, attempt to compare the before and after with a text editor or a hex editor.  You may discover clues as to what actually changed.